# Getting float value from the database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server and in one of the tables I have a nullable float column.  When I look at that value in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I have a value in one of the records as `1.3`.  I also have a client app that gets data from the database via Entity Framework (EF) and it has a corresponding nullable double (double?) property for that column. Now when I get a value from the database it has 1.2999999523162842 values in it.

All these records (more than 1 million) will be used in interpolation, extrapolation, calculation and any smallest deviation becomes a significant value. So all values on the client side have to match values in the database.

I can't round on the client side to the first decimal number, because in the database there are values with 2, 3, 4, or more decimal points.

My question is how can I make sure that all values in the database will be the same values on the client after loading them from database via EF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't `float` a *binary* floating point value in SQL Server? If so, your value isn't *really* 1.3, as that isn't exactly representable in binary floating point. Options:

- Perhaps your field is effectively a *decimal* floating (or fixed) point type, in which case you should use `decimal` on the .NET side as well.
- If you're using binary floating point in SQL server, I'd expect the result in .NET to be the same: the nearest binary floating point value of the appropriate type to the number you originally entered. Just because SQL Server is *showing* you the value as 1.3 doesn't mean it *is* exactly 1.3.

Using my [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs), it looks like the closest `double` value to 1.3 is actually 1.3000000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125 - so I'm not sure why you'd be getting the value you're actually seeing. The closest *`float`* value is 1.2999999523162841796875, which sounds like it's what you're getting. So it's as if your value in the database is being converted as a 32-bit floating point number instead of a 64-bit one.

Is your database field actually something like `FLOAT(23)`? If so, that corresponds with a .NET `float` instead of `double`. That would explain things.

Comment: Or presumably it could be possible that somewhere between database and where it is being tested in the code it has been forced through a float accidentally somewhere?

Comment: @Chris: Possibly - but I'm assuming for the moment that the OP has reported the result as soon as it's come from the database. I think a problematic schema is the more likely culprit, but who knows? :)

Comment: Yeah, I just recall many times having problems with string data coming out of the database truncated and it turned out that it was fine in the database, its just that a stored procedure that used it was trying to put it into a varchar(50) when it was a varchar(100). Takes ages to figure out if you aren't really thinking about it because you don't think to check that your variables are the right size until you've been bitten by that a few times. :) The OP can worry about it from now though. :)

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I checked database and database has float(53).  Also I am checking value right after I pulled data from table by EF, so there are no conversions or anything in between done.  When I was using EF designer, EF designer automatically created double? property for that column.  So as you can see I have Float(53) - 8 bytes in the database and I have double in C# code.

Comment: @Vlad: In that case it *ought* to be okay. What happens if you try to *populate* the data with the-closest-double-to-1.3? Can you then read it out again? Do you appreciate the point that the actual value will never be exactly 1.3?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks for your help.  Since I have more than million records and any small value deviation becomes after interpolation, extrapolation and computation significant value.  I am comparing .NET value with SAS value (SAS doesn't have this issue) and I see some significant differences in the result (starting with second decimal point) and this is not acceptable for our business.

Comment: @Vlad: Well whatever SAS is doing, you're still *not* storing exactly 1.3 in the database, as I've said. It's important that you understand that. You should also understand that other differences between floating point operations on different systems can have effects - you should very rarely expect to get *exactly* the same results between two systems after performing multiple computations using binary floating point. In particular, in some cases the CLR may use 80-bit arithmetic, and in others it will limit itself to 64-bit arithmetic.

Comment: @Jon:  Thanks again.  It is actually very interesting, but in LINQPad I am getting the same values as in database (e.g. 1.3) using LINQ to EF

Comment: @Vlad: It's not really clear what you mean. Could you clarify? It sounds like you're saying that EF is only broken within your app... in which case you need to find out where in your app the problem is occurring, which I can't really help you with as I know nothing about your app.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks again.  I used following "var result = from v in xxx where v.ImportId == 3 && v.RoundID == 98230 select v.Raised;" statement LINQPad which uses EF to pull that data and I got result result = 1.51, however I am getting 1.5099999904632568 value in VS using "var result = context.xxx.Where(x => x.ImportId == GlobalData.ImportId && x.RoundID == 98230).Single();"

Comment: @Vlad: How are you *displaying* the value in each case though? I wouldn't be at all surprised if this was just a matter of the same value being displayed in different ways. Try printing each out using `Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("r"))`.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you so much for helping me on this issue.  I tried like you suggested using Console.WriteLine(result.Value.ToString("r")) and I am getting 1.51 in LINQPad and 1.5099999904632568 in Console window from VS.

Comment: @Vlad: Weird. Again, the value you're getting is the one you'd get if you were doing everything using `float` instead of `double`. Just out of interest - and I know this sounds weird - does your app use DirectX at all?

Comment: @Jon: You are right it sounds weird, and I am not using DirectX.

Comment: @Vlad: At this point it's probably worth trying to start from a minimal project, chopping out bits until you don't have this 64-to-32 bit data loss... or work up from the bottom and add bits in until it comes back again. I'd at least start with a console app built with the same kind of settings as your real app.

Comment: @Jon:  Thanks Jon for all your help.  I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Jon:  In edmx file I have mapping to my table as <Property Name="Raised" Type="float" /> which is generated by EF, and maybe that is the root of all issues?  What is the default float in EF?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Vlad: That could well be the issue. I'm not really an Entity Framework person, but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399548.aspx suggests that really does mean a 32-bit float. Try changing it to double and see if that fixes it... but also see if you can work out why it was float to start with!